# Set the default value for an HTML <select> element in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I set the default value for an HTML  element in angular2?
The simplest way to go would be my following attempt.
This does not work yet, could somebody help me please?

```
// extract from template
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status">Status: </label>
  <select class="form-control" name="status" #status="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="statusValueToSet" required>
    <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
    <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status">{{status}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

// in the component class  
statuses:string[] = ["New", "Accepted", "Invalid"];
```

Comment: Does giving a value to `statusValueToSet` beforehand not help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize `statusValueToSet` in your class body, but leave the `Choose here` option in the select:

```
// extract from template
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status">Status: </label>
  <select class="form-control" name="status" #status="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="statusValueToSet" required>
    <option [value]="''">Choose here</option>
    <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status">{{status}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

statuses: string[] = ["New", "Accepted", "Invalid"];
statusValueToSet: string = "";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is now, that the initial value 'default' is already a valid form. Any idea for a quick fix?

Comment: I think I found something - just using an empty string as value seems to invalidate it.